# redirecting using knockout.js - using a if not statement

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to do a redirect if a knockout binding is false, I don't know what I need to put within my KO statement to allow it to redirect.
my code:

```
<!-- ko if not: Days() != null && Days().length > 0 -->
        MY REDIRECT HERE????     
<!--/ko-->
```

Anybody know a good way to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do a redirection there, but I would rather subscribe to the `Days` in the view model and redirect by changing `window.location.href`.